# Scrapy can't find form on page

Tags: html, python-3.x, xpath, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm trying to write a spider that will automatically log in to [this website](https://www.athletic.net/account/login/?ReturnUrl=%2Fdefault.aspx). However, when I try using `scrapy.FormRequest.from_response` in the shell I get the error:

`No <form> element found in <200 https://www.athletic.net/account/login/?ReturnUrl=%2Fdefault.aspx>`

I can definitely see the form when I inspect element on the site, but it just did not show up in Scrapy when I tried finding it using `response.xpath()` either. Is it possible for the form content to be hidden from my spider somehow? If so, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The form is created using Javascript, it's not part of the static HTML source code. Scrapy does not parse Javascript, thus it cannot be found.

The relevant part of the static HTML (where they inject the form using Javascript) is:

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl as appC" class="m-auto pt-3 pb-5 container" style="max-width: 425px;">
    <section ui-view></section>
</div>
```

To find issues like this, I would either:

- compare the source code from "View Source Code" and "Inspect" to each other
- browse the web page with a browser without Javascript (when I develop scrapers I usually have one browser with Javascript for research and documentations and another one for checking web pages without Javascript)

In this case, you have to manually create your FormRequest for this web page. I was not able to spot any form of CSRF protection on their form, so it might be as simple as:

```
FormRequest(url='https://www.athletic.net/account/auth.ashx',
            formdata={"e": "foo@example.com", "pw": "secret"})
```

However, I think you cannot use `formdata`, but instead they expect you to send JSON. Not sure if `FormRequest` can handle this, I guess you just want to use a standard `Request`.

Since they heavily use Javascript on their front end, you cannot use the source code of the page to find these parameters either. Instead, I used the developer console of my browser and checked the request/response that happened when I tried to login with invalid credentials.

This gave me:

```
General:
Request URL: https://www.athletic.net/account/auth.ashx
[...]

Request Payload:
{e: "foo@example.com", pw: "secret"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Scrapy has a JsonRequest class to help with posting JSON. See here [https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html]

So something like the below should work

```
data = {"password": "pword", "username": "user"}

# JSON POST to API login URL
return JsonRequest( 
        url=url,
        callback=self.after_login,
        data=data,
    )
```