# scrapy encounters ValueError: No <form> element found in <200

Tags: python, scrapy

Following the [scrapy tutorial](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html?highlight=JSON#using-formrequest-from-response-to-simulate-a-user-login), I'm trying to simulate a user login to [a website](https://accounts.douban.com/login)

The code I wrote is as below:

```
def parse(self, response):
    return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
        response,
        formdata={'username': 'john', 'password': 'secret'},
        callback=self.after_login
    )
```

However, I get this error:

```
ValueError: No <form> element found in <200 https://accounts.douban.com/passport/login>
```

How do I fix this?

[A related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51123715/12214867) probably encounters Javascript created form, mine doesn't seem to face the same problem, as the page my crawler downloaded contains the form

```
<div class="account-form-field">
  <input id="password" type="password" name="password" class="account-form-input password" placeholder="密码" tabindex="3">
  <span class="icon openpwd hide"></span>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://accounts.douban.com/passport/get_password" class="fwd-link">找回密码</a>
</div>
```

When I monitored the login process, I found that there are some stat.html before basic, should I do something to simulate this?

[image]

Does anyone know how to solve this issue? Your help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: because the site `https://accounts.douban.com/passport/login` no <form> tag,you can use F12 with chrome or firefox find the real login request url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To login to that website you have to use different formdata:

```
formdata = {
    'ck': '',
    'name': 'john',
    'password': 'secret',
    'remember': 'false',
    'ticket': ''
}
```

and different login url:

```
https://accounts.douban.com/j/mobile/login/basic
```

```
def start_requests(self):
        formdata = {
            'ck': '',
            'name': 'john',
            'password': 'secret',
            'remember': 'false',
            'ticket': ''
        }

        yield scrapy.FormRequest(
                url='https://accounts.douban.com/j/mobile/login/basic',
                formdata=formdata,
                callback=self.parse
            )
```

and no error

Comment: no error, if use formdata and url I mentioned ```2020-07-03 14:20:11 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST https://accounts.douban.com/j/mobile/login/basic> (referer: None)```